# How to merge a jpg with a gif without lossing the animation of gif file?

Tags: imagemagick, gif, jpeg

I am trying to merge a splash screen image which is in `jpg` format with an ajaxloader which is in `gif` format.

I tried the following command using ImageMagik:

`convert -delay 50 splashimage.jpg ajaxloader.gif final.gif`

This command does merge the `gif` file with the `jpg` image but the loader appear at the top-left corner.

I was wondering if there is an option available to place it at a specfic (x,y) point on the `jpg` image?

If anybody has had done a similar thing or has an idea as to how a similar thing can be achieved, please guide me through.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by designing individual frames of images with the desired location of my text and merged them using Imagemagik.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? You'd be turning a nice 24bit JPG into a crappy quality single frame on an 8bit gif. You could just use some CSS tricks to overlay the loader .gif on top of the .jpg on a webpage, which would not sacrifice any image quality to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I can't do this in my case, its not possible the way the app works. I have to merge them.. any suggestions for this?